# What 'color' is each Berry?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-sixth-generation

So I was trying to make the different Mulches and the little girl at the field says that the kind of Mulch that comes out of the composter is based on the color of the Berries. So what color is each Berry?

I was going to look into it further myself but I do not have access to most of the berries in my own game at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good list and also the source is a decent guide for farming Berries.

- Blue: Apicot, Coba, Kelpsy, Maranga, Oran, Passho, Rowap, Yache
- Green: Aguav, Babiri, Durin, Hondew, Kebia, Lum, Micle, Rabuta,
  Rawst, Rindo, Salac, Starf, Tanga, Wepear
- Pink: Mago, Magost, Nanab, Pecha, Persim, Petaya, Roseli, Watmel
- Purple: Belue, Bluk, Chesto, Colbur, Cornn, Ganlon, Kasib, Pamtre,
  Payapa, Wiki
- Red: Cheri, Chople, Custap, Figy, Haban, Lansat, Leppa, Liechi, Occa,
  Pomeg, Spelon, Tamato
- Yellow: Aspear, Charti, Chilan, Grepa, Iapapa, Jaboca, Kee, Nomel,
  Pinap, Qualot, Shuca, Sitrus, Wacan

Source: [Ultimate Berry Farm Guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67566377)